# How to perform automatic refresh of extension after installation in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hi I need to know if there is any way to perform auto refreshment of extension after installation.Currently I am using alarms to refresh the extension.But I need to perform automatic refreshment of extension after installation.Is there any way to perform it?Please help me. Below is my code by using alarms.
here is my background.js

```
 var oldChromeVersion = !chrome.runtime;
 function getGmailUrl() {
 return "http://calpinemate.com/";
 }


   function isGmailUrl(url) {
  return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;
   }

 if (chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.onStartup) {
  chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  updateIcon();
   });
 } else {
 chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {
 updateIcon();
 });
 }
           function onInit() {
                updateIcon();

       if (!oldChromeVersion) {
          chrome.alarms.create('watchdog', {periodInMinutes:5});
            }

              }


     function onAlarm(alarm) {
    console.log('Got alarm', alarm);
       if (alarm && alarm.name == 'watchdog') {
       onWatchdog();
       } 
     else {
          updateIcon();
              }

           }

      function onWatchdog() {

        chrome.alarms.get('refresh', function(alarm) {
       if (alarm) {
       console.log('Refresh alarm exists.');
        } 
              else {

           updateIcon();

              }
           });

           }


       if (oldChromeVersion) {

           updateIcon();
         onInit();

           } 

           else {

          chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInit);
         chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(onAlarm);
           }

        function updateIcon(){

       .....//certain functions are performed
   }
```

Comment: Presently after enabling the extension and reloading it only performs the above functions.I need it to perform just before reloading extension

Comment: Please change your code to the smallest possible sample that reproduces your problem. Currently the code appears to be much bigger than the specific question you're asking. Also, what does this have to do with Linux?

Comment: I have updated my code.please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have your operations run when the extension is installed (which is something totally different from being disabled and re-enabled):

Replace that line:

```
chrome.alarms.create('watchdog', {periodInMinutes:5});
```

With this line:

```
chrome.alarms.create('watchdog', {
    periodInMinutes: 5,
    delayInMinutes:  0
});
```

---

If you want your operations to be run when the extension is enabled:

On a new line at the very, very end of your file add this:

```
onInit();
```