# How to refresh an extension automatically on installing it in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, installation

Hi I am in need to refresh an extension automatically just on installation in chrome extension.When I enable the extension at the moment certain actions should be performed.Presently after enabling and then reloading only the actions are performed.But I need those actions to be performed just when the extension is enabled.Also I am using alarms for periodic checking.So that in every 5 min the checking is performed.
Here is my background.js

```
  var oldChromeVersion = !chrome.runtime;
       function getGmailUrl() {
       return "http://calpinemate.com/";
            } 
  function isGmailUrl(url) {
  return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;
   }

    if (chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.onStartup) {
      chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
          updateIcon();
        });
       } else {
       chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {
          updateIcon();
          });
         }
       function onInit() {
            updateIcon();

   if (!oldChromeVersion) {
      chrome.alarms.create('watchdog', {periodInMinutes:5});
        }
          }
       function onAlarm(alarm) {
       console.log('Got alarm', alarm);
           if (alarm && alarm.name == 'watchdog') {
           onWatchdog();
            } 
         else {
      updateIcon();
          }
      }

    function onWatchdog() {
    chrome.alarms.get('refresh', function(alarm) {
     if (alarm) {
     console.log('Refresh alarm exists.');
    } 
          else {
       updateIcon();

          }
       });

       }
     if (oldChromeVersion) {
       updateIcon();
       onInit();

       } 
      else {

      chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInit);
       chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(onAlarm);
       }

    function updateIcon(){

   .....//certain functions are performed
       }
```

In the above code i need to perform function updateIcon() when the extension is enabled.Now according to my code , what happens is that this function is performed either in every 5 min or by reloading the extension after enabling.I can't figure out what is happening?What I ahve to do in order to perform at the time of enabling?

Comment: How many times do you plan on posting the same question ? "Possible" duplicate of **[that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369102/how-to-perform-automatic-refresh-of-extension-after-installation-in-chrome-exten)** (among others)...

Comment: Hi I have found the answer by myself... by adding chrome.management.onEnabled.addListener(function (){
 updateIcon();   
});

Comment: This is a viable alternative, but has a couple of disadvantages: 1. You will need the additional "management" permission. 2. The event will be triggered when **any** extension or packaged App get enabled, so it might be a good idea to filter based on `ExtensionInfo.id`. But, like I said, this is sure a viable solution. Good find ! (check the other duplicate question, for an alternative solution).

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369102/how-to-perform-automatic-refresh-of-extension-after-installation-in-chrome-exten